# How to get notifications when I reach internet enabled area (wifi circle)?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7

Presently I'm working on a Windows Phone application that will work in both online and offline mode. So that if the net is available means I need to sync my offline data to the respective server. My requirement is if my app is working and when I reach a wifi-enabled circle (area) I need to get a notification. Otherwise need to race an event.

How can I achieve this? Is there any notification channel present in WP7 to inform about this? If yes please demonstrate some code to achieve the goal.

Comment: Are you trying to auto sync offline data when wifi connection found? Or simply notify the user?

Comment: you are absolutely rit Giborn, yup i need to auto sync offline data when wifi connection found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The platform does not include support for the "GeoFencing" scenario you describe.

The best solution currently available is to periodically (using a Background Task) check to see if a connection is available and to begin the sync then.

Answer (score 5):

You can determine if you are connected to a network, you can get the connection type and the phone informs you when it goes on/offline:

- `NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()` checks if you are online or offline
- `DeviceNetworkInformation` tells you more about the network type (Wifi, ...)
- `NetworkChange.NetworkAddressChanged += new NetworkAddressChangedEventHandler(OnNetworkChangeHandler);` registers a listener to listen for changes

[Click here for an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getisnetworkavailable%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) on how to listen for changes. Also very good is [this tutorial from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh487166%28v=VS.92%29.aspx), demonstrating all the goodies mentioned above!

I also recommend reading [this blog post](http://gdwp7dev.wordpress.com/2010/10/24/zune-detection-and-network-awareness/) as it contains much valuable information about the different APIs.

PS: It is not possible to get a list of all available WLANs around the phone. You can only see the WLAN you are connected to (if). That is a limitation of the Windows Phone API.